# npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted

Tags: npm, create-react-app

Running from a Windows Powershell as Administrator, I have tried all of the below. Nothing works. Not only that, it takes like 20 minutes to get to the error.

- Upgrading node
- Upgradeing npm
- Turning off AntiVirus
- Cleaning the mpm cache
- Verifying the npm cache

Here is the output from trying to create a project:

```
PS D:\Documents\js> create-react-app socket-io-client

Creating a new React app in D:\Documents\js\socket-io-client.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...


> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall D:\Documents\js\socket-io-client\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js

npm ERR! path D:\Documents\js\socket-io-client\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall rmdir
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'D:\Documents\js\socket-io-client\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'D:\Documents\js\socket-io-client\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir \'D:\\Documents\\js\\socket-io-client\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rmdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'D:\\Documents\\js\\socket-io-client\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\idf\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-08-15T04_50_32_705Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... node_modules
```

Comment: I believe I understand the problem. I had another node application running. When I stopped it and retried create-react-app, it went all the way through without problems. I did  update node.js and npm thought, and at least one of those is also necessary.

Answer (score 7):

I know you have resolved your issue.  But in case somebody else got the same error message, what ended up working for me was deleting these folders.

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
```

If the problem still persists, try one of the fixes from this thread: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10826.

Answer (score 1):

npm cache verify worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i don't know how but
after **updating the npm**...
all the commands worked fine for me.

I was trying to install react-router-dom and got the above error.

Comment: This could work but referring to https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-cache @KarnRatana solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/46046889/5667103 seems to be the way to go here, since the garbage collector could not succeed by Ivan